# Took a trip to a parallel universe, need help deciphering

Tags: rebus, english

I recently traveled to a parallel universe where the people wrote in a symbol-heavy language seemingly derived from English. While there, I attended various sorts of collegiate lectures to get a feel for the language; during a particular lecture, I saw this inscription written upon the board:

$$\bbox[13px,border:1px solid black]{(\vee\sqcup):\quad2\text{think}\enspace\wedge\enspace\square=\blacksquare\enspace\wedge\enspace\text{GABA}+\text{crime}}$$

**What does it say? What was the lecture about?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the lecture (or at least that part of it) was about

> George Orwell's novel *1984*.

The inscription

> refers to three key notions of the Party's thought-control in that book:
>  $\mathrm{2think}$: doublethink
>  $\square=\blacksquare$: blackwhite
>  $\mathrm{GABA}+\mathrm{crime}$: crimestop
>  (GABA is the main *inhibitory* neurotransmitter in our nervous systems).
>  These are joined together with $\wedge$ which I assume simply signifies "and" as it does in our universe's mathematical logic.

The mysterious prefix $\vee\sqcup$

> is a terrible pun: $\vee$ signifies OR and $\sqcup$ is a picture of a WELL.

Comment: That's actually a stupendous pun, IMO. Upvote to OP :)

Comment: SPOILER ALERT: I haven’t read that novel in a long time, but wouldn’t “thoughtcrime” fit?

Comment: I guess it would fit about as well as "crimestop", depending on whether you say GABA is an inhibitory _neurotransmitter_ or an _inhibitory_ neurotransmitter :-).